# Google sheets MATCH function not finding 0?

Tags: google-sheets

[Here's my sheet that I'm using](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X9vW-0cviq4oVgjKtEpAHojP-9ppiFCE_uVvtUT-UQc/edit?usp=sharing).
Why is the match function not finding that zero?

Basically, I have a set of numbers:

```
7,244.500
5,465.347
6,923.077
6,923.077
4,084.352
4,418.520
3,685.967
0,000.000
```

I want a match function to find the 0,000.000, and my current function is

```
=MATCH(0,C2:C9)
```

But it just keeps returning #N/A, and says it can't find the value "0" in the range. Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the "range" `C2:C9` is not sorted, you need to override the default assumption of sorted by adding a third parameter `0`, meaning "unsorted, and exact match".

Use `=MATCH(0,Info!C2:C9,0)`.

Comment: Not totally bad, just in a rush. `1` is the default, "sorted ascending, return match or highest that is less than target." `-1` means "sorted descending, return match or lowest that is higher than target."